# How to include AX extension in OpenID auth request using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

How to make attribute exchange request in dotnetopenauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to get standard attributes, I recommend you read about the [AXFetchAsSregTransform](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/) which hides the complexity of AX and SREG attribute gathering from your site.

If you are doing something custom and know what AX attributes you need to request, here is sample code:

```
var rp = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var request = rp.CreateRequest("=some*identifier");
var ax = new FetchRequest();
ax.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
request.AddExtension(ax);
request.RedirectToProvider();
```

Comment: page not found. I think dotnetopenauth has made some major changes in site structure. Almost every link in SO are 404